# PostgreSQL timezone offset having negative in minutes part `(-02:-30)`

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to all the timezone name and offset value from  `pg_timezone_names` but few of the offset having negative symbol in minute part.

here is the query

```
select name, to_char(utc_offset, 'HH24:MI' ), utc_offset
from pg_timezone_names
WHERE  name LIKE '%Canada/Newfoundland%'
ORDER  BY name;
```

and the result is

[image]

as seen in the result the offset `(-02:-30)` has a negative symbol. The expected result will be `-02:30`. Is there any possible way in Postgres to format offset value like this?

Answer (score 2):

Why not?:

```
select name,  utc_offset::varchar, utc_offset 
from pg_timezone_names
WHERE  name LIKE '%Canada/Newfoundland%'
ORDER  BY name;
        name         | utc_offset | utc_offset 
---------------------+------------+------------
 Canada/Newfoundland | -02:30:00  | -02:30:00
(1 row)
```

For your purposes `to_char()` is just the long way around to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Since the length of the result set will always be the same, why don't just cut the minutes off with `substring` and `length`?

```
SELECT name, substring(utc_offset::text,1,length(utc_offset::text)-3), utc_offset
FROM pg_timezone_names
WHERE  name LIKE '%Canada/Newfoundland%'
ORDER  BY name;

           name            | substring | utc_offset 
---------------------------+-----------+------------
 Canada/Newfoundland       | -02:30    | -02:30:00
 posix/Canada/Newfoundland | -02:30    | -02:30:00
(2 rows)
```